# Are variance and unfairness sum perfectly related?

Tags: summation, integers, variance

This question is basically a part of an [algorithmic problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63774153/10145519) about dynamic programming I was trying to solve.

***You need to consider two things that I'm about to compare below:***

1. Variance
2. Unfairness Sum - defined and explained below

## Unfairness Sum-

Let's say we have a list of positive integers denoted as `myList`. The Unfairness Sum of `myList` is defined as the sum of the absolute differences of all the pairs (explained below) in myList.

***To Explain***
For example, if

myList = $\{1, 2, 5, 5, 6\}$

Then the Unfairness Sum will be (note that numbers are considered unique based on their index-or position- in list, not their values)

$$\text{Unfairness Sum}= |1-2| + |1-5| + |1-5| + |1-6| + |2-5| + |2-5| + |2-6| + |5-5| + |5-6| + |5-6|$$

## What I want to know

Can I say that variance & Unfairness Sum are perfectly related (I know they are strongly related because this approach of variance has worked for half of my test cases - having up to a max of 9000 integers`)?

***In other words,***
Can I say that among a lots of lists of positive integers, a list with minimum variance will always be the list with Minimum unfairness sum?

Comment: The way you have defined it, *every* list has a minimum unfairness sum. So I think your question is about minimum variance versus minimum minimum unfairness sum.

Comment: @Gerry I realized it now. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Also thank you @integrand for helping me out by editing the question according to math formatting styles :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list that minimizes the absolute sum does not always minimize the variance sum.   Consider two lists:
$\{1, 1, x\}$ and $\{1, 2, 3\}$
where $x$ is a real number that satisfies $x \geq 1$.

We get
\begin{align}
a(1,2,3) &= |1-2| + |1-3| + |2-3| = 4\\
v(1,2,3) &= (1-2)^2 + (2-2)^2 + (3-2)^2 = 2
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
a(1,1,x) &= |1-1| + |1-x| +  |1-x| = 2(x-1)\\
v(1,1,x) &= (1 - \frac{(2+x)}{3})^2 + (1 - \frac{(2+x)}{3})^2 + (x - \frac{(2+x)}{3})^2
\end{align}
where we have used $x\geq 1$ to claim $|1-x|=x-1$.
We want to find $x\geq 1$ that satisfies:
\begin{align}
&a(1,2,3) > a(1,1,x)\\
&v(1,2,3)<v(1,1,x)
\end{align}

---

To find such a value $x\geq 1$, we have
$$a(1,2,3)>a(1,1,x) \iff 4 > 2(x-1) \iff x<3$$
However
\begin{align}
&v(1,2,3)<v(1,1,x) \\
&\iff 2<(1 - \frac{(2+x)}{3})^2 + (1 - \frac{(2+x)}{3})^2 + (x - \frac{(2+x)}{3})^2
\end{align}
There are values $x \geq 1$ that satisfy both inequalities, for example $x=2.8$.

Comment: Interesting... However `x` has to be a positive integer not a floating point (decimal value) number, does that make a difference?

Comment: It does not make a difference.  Just multiply everything by a factor of 10. Note that $a(10(b_1, ..., b_n)) = 10a(b_1, ..., b_n)$ and $v(10(b_1,...,b_n)) = 100v(b_1, ..., b_n)$.

Comment: That does it for me, thank you for your help :)

Comment: I will consider what happened with me in regards of my test cases, was a coincidence (or a strong relation)

Comment: Now that my original question has been answered, I have 2 doubts remaining. (A) Although i'm entirely certain on this one but as I am ready to know something unexpected, will that be any different case if I consider `standard deviation` instead of `variance` ? (B) Regarding the fact you proved that `minimum variance doesn't always imply minimum unfairness sum` - is that because of the fact that `variance` depends on `outliers` heavily and will `standard deviation` improve or affect that dependency? . Forgive me if i'm being silly here.

Comment: You can check the same example for standard deviation, the resulting inequality needed is $\sqrt{v(1,2,3)}<\sqrt{v(1,1,x)}$ which is different but is satisfied when $x>(3+\sqrt{3})/3$, for which $x=2.8$ also works: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%282%29%3Csqrt%282%281-%282%2Bx%29%2F3%29%5E2+%2B+%28x-%282%2Bx%29%2F3%29%5E2%29 The quadratic penalty associated with outliers is indeed the intuition that I used to construct this example. But in general nonlinear operations can be unusual and it is no surprise that different nonlinear operations result in different orderings.

Comment: That makes sense to now. That was amazing. Thank You